# Compression algorithms based on bit-strings that are very simple to implement?

Tags: haskell, compression, bitstring

Given the type of bitstrings in Haskell:

```
data Bits = O Bits | I Bits | Nil
```

Are there compression algorithms that have satisfactory results (specially when it comes to repeated substrings), that are very small and simple to implement as idiomatic recursive Haskell functions? Ideally, the algorithm would operate on bitstrings, not lists of characters; thus, it should identify repeated substrings of arbitrary lengths and positions. I'm asking for references (i.e., names/citations); no need to post the complete code.

Comment: To whoever voted to close: note that I'm not asking for software or library recommendations, I'm asking to name algorithms. Is that against the guidelines?

Comment: I think the question is a bit opinion-based: what does it mean for an algorithm to be "simple" and "idiomatic", and what are "satisfactory results"?

Comment: Also, do you mean consecutive repetitions or duplicated substrings in general?

Comment: @Noughtmare I mean an algorithm that can perhaps be implemented in a few recursive functions without many dependencies using mostly pattern-matching. But how else can I define that? If I just ask for a compression algorithm in general, there are many that I can easily find on Google, so this question wouldn't be needed. But I really need one that can be implemented in a few lines of normal Haskell. And I mean duplicated substrings in general, basically I want it to be able to detect repeated words and compress them.

Comment: Run-length encoding is very easy to define, and works well if you have long repeating strings. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)